# how to get permissions for a network appliction?

Tags: c#

my application is communicating on udp ports when i start application my application it asks for "allow" and some times throws exception. how can i set all permissions to my application on load event using c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is the windows firewall message. Here's the way to add the exceptions to windows firewall

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c14167/Programatically-Add-Exceptions-to-a-Windows-Firewall-Using-C.htm